# How can I fix the train set and test set in python?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Suppose I have a data set with 1000 rows. I want to split it into train and test set. I want to split first 800 row into train set then rest 200 row into test set. Is it possible?

[image: image of portion of sample data set]

My python test code for train and test splitting is like this:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20)
```

Comment: If I am understanding correctly you don't want the shuffled which is the behaviour of train_test_split, if so are you using numpy or pandas, or something else?

Comment: Pandas. i just want to make sure that my first 800 data( sequentially) will in the train section then rest 200 is in the test section.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, I will run by a few of them.

**Slicing** is a powerful method in python and accepts the arguments as `data[start:stop:step]` in your case if you just want the first 800 copies and your data frame is named as `train` for input features and `Y` for output features you can use

```
X_train = train[0:800]
X_test = train[800:]
y_train = Y[0:800]
y_test = Y[800:]
```

**Iloc** function is associated with a dataFrame and is associated with an Index, if your Index is numeric then you can use

```
X_train = train.iloc[0:800]
X_test = train.iloc[800:]
y_train = Y.iloc[0:800]
y_test = Y.iloc[800:]
```

If you just have to split the data into two parts, you can even use the `df.head()` and `df.tail()` to do it,

```
X_train = train.head(800)
X_test = train.tail(200)
y_train = Y.head(800)
y_test = Y.tail(200)
```

There are other ways to do it too, I would recommend using the first method as it is common across multiple datatypes and will also work if you were working with a numpy array. To learn more about slicing I would suggest that you checkout. [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) here it is explained for a list, but it works with almost all forms.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set `shuffle= False`.

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.20, shuffle = False)
```